# Slick Carousel full screen vertical slide gap between section

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using slick carousel from [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and set it as vertical slide and use jquery to set height section to full screen.

Anyone know if I am missing something, when I slide to 4th slide and 5th, I can see the previous slide background color on the top where 1st,2nd,3rd do not have this problem.

I dont know if code snippet can show it, I provide [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/453991/) here. Thank you.

```js
initFullSlide();

function initFullSlide() {
  var $fullSlide = $("#full-slide");
  var $sections = $(".section");
  $sections.css({ height: $(window).height() - 60 });
  var slickIsChanging = false;
  var slideIndex = 0;
  var slideCount = $(".section").length;

  function mouseWheel($slider) {
    $fullSlide.on(
      "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel MozMousePixelScroll",
      {
        $slider: $slider
      },
      mouseWheelHandler
    );
  }

  function mouseWheelHandler(event) {
    // console.log("wheel");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $slideContainer = $(this);
    if (!$slideContainer.hasClass("animating") && slickIsChanging == false) {
      $slideContainer.addClass("animating");
      var $slider = event.data.$slider;
      var delta = event.originalEvent.deltaY;
      if (delta > 0) {
        $slider.slick("slickNext");
        
      } else {
        $slider.slick("slickPrev");
        
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        $slideContainer.removeClass("animating");
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  $fullSlide
    .on("init", function() {
      //slick slider callback must be defined before creating slick object
      // console.log("init");
      mouseWheel($fullSlide);
    })
    .on("beforeChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      //console.log("change start");
      slickIsChanging = true;
    })
    .on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      //console.log("change done");
      slickIsChanging = false;
    })
    .slick({
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false,
      vertical: true,
      verticalSwiping: true,
      draggable: true,
      dots: false,
      placeholders:false
      // variableWidth:true,
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#full-slide.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  border: none;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  border: none;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #1dcde4;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #d17205;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #1305d1;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #ced105;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #d10505;
}
.section {
  width: 100%;
}
.section img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div id="full-slide">
        <div class="section">
            Text here
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1190x334/d8d8d8/787878?text=img">
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            Second text
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1190x334/d8d8d8/787878?text=img2">
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1190x334/d8d8d8/787878?text=img3">
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1190x334/d8d8d8/787878?text=img4">
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1190x334/d8d8d8/787878?text=img5">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hugely helpful question and answer below, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @user7290573 using `font-size:0` works too but the article referenced said it can have problem too in android.

So I research a little bit further. Actually example from here [codepen](https://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/mMLQQb) run just fine but it is using slick 1.7 where I am using the latest 1.9.

I saw those child `div` structure are different between versions. So adding `.section{display:block !important;}`also work.

I read a little further again why those structure are different and found out a solution by just adding **`.slick({rows:0})`** during initiation. So I am using this at the moment. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/archie_lee/dof2xa95/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `font-size` property of the parent container to 0 as the gaps you're seeing are caused by whitespace between each of the carousel elements. [Here's an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/454664/).

[Here's some more information on the whitespace "bug".](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)